# Using jQuery with Magento without replacing $ with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I've not really found a definitive answer for this question. I've had to edit jQuery plugins to replace instances of $. This, for me at least, is a serious issue. Anyone coming after me, if going to have a nightmare to maintain of upgrade my work. I use a lot of plugins.

Is this really the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the plugin is poorly written then I guess you could try using the [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method.

If it's properly written you don't need it because it will already wrap all `$` usages in an anonymous method:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2):

As Darin has mentioned, well authored plugins are wrapped in an anonymous method. You can use the same trick in your own code too, rather than use `noConflict` - for example if you had a JavaScript file with loads of jQuery in it that you didn't want to update:

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#myid').hide();
    });

    // and so on...

}(jQuery));
```